# ESLint Rule to enforce not to use parentheses for single argument arrow functions

Tags: eslint

I want to know whether there is an ESLint Rule to enforce developer not to use parentheses for single argument arrow functions.

```
// good
const handleKeyValues = prop => {

// warn
const handleKeyValues = (prop) => {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [arrow-parens](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-parens) rule with "as-needed" value should enforce that.